# Django: Getting error with arguments in decorator in certain setup

Tags: django, arguments, decorator

I usually work on an Ubuntu 10.04 machine with python 2.6 installed in it. I have the following decorator:

```
def owner_required(view_func, Model):
    '''
    checks if the object is being accessed but its owner
    '''
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = Model.objects.get(pk=int(kwargs['pk']))
            if obj.user == request.user:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponse('Forbidden')
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator(view_func)
```

Everything is working as expected in the same machine.

The problem appears when I try to run it in my laptop, which has Ubuntu 11.10 and python 2.7.2.

Whatever page, I try to access, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: owner_required() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

In my myapp/urls.py, I have the following line, which is causing the error:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', name = 'my_view', \
view = owner_required(login_required(\      
DetailView.as_view(model=MyModel,\
template_name='myapp/view.html')),MyModel))
```

So, `owner_required` is receiving 2 arguments: the result of `login_required` and `MyModel`

What could be causing the problem? I'm only giving my ubuntu and python versions, since I don know what else could cause this. What other "variables" should I look at to solve this problem? Both are running under virtualenv and the same django version 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You have probably tried this, but just wanted to ask. I used to get a similar error when an old compiled view was cached in the server, especially right after some edits, and all I had to do was restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what version of `owner_required` has been used you could check it's `func_code` property.

For example on my local machine `login_required` placed in */media/projects/blablabla/apps/common/utils.py*:

```
login_required.func_code
# <code object login_required at 0x1e75f30, file "/media/projects/blablabla/apps/common/utils.py", line 102>
```

hope this helps )